# Object destructuring into another object does not work

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Today I had to merge two objects, picking the properties of an object `a` and placing them in an object `b`. I can't understand why the first syntax/statement is not working, while the second one is.

```
let user = { a: 1, b: 2 };
let data = { z: 1, c: 3, f: 8, d: 4 };

// Let's say I want user to be { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

// method 1 (not works) 
const r1 = {
    ...user,
    ...({c} = data)
};
document.getElementById("r1").innerText = JSON.stringify(r1);

// method 2 (works)
const r2 = {
    ...user,
    ...(({c}) => ({c}))(data)
};
document.getElementById("r2").innerText = JSON.stringify(r2);
```

You can try the code on https://jsfiddle.net/Ljb7ndp4/6/

Comment: well `{c} = data` is creating a variable `c` and not an object `console.log(c)` would show 3

Comment: Yes, your global scope now contains a variable c with the contents of data.c. The expression ({c} = data) returns the original object, which is why r1 contains the merged contents of both objects.

Comment: in the second case you're calling a anonymous function, passing `data` to arguments, then you're destructuring the arguments extracting `c`, the function finally returns an object with c inside

Comment: @epascarello You're right, I haven't tought about that, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second method you are creating an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), "an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) is a JavaScript function that runs as soon as it is defined". The IIFE on method 2 is returning an object like `{c: <value>}`. As objects support the spread operator, you are able to use it in the object definition.

To visualize it in your code, you can assign the result of the IIFE to a variable and print the result on console.

```js
const val = (({c}) => ({c}))(data)
console.log(val) // { c: 3 }
```

The arrow function syntax, in this case, makes a little bit harder to visualize what is happening, but the code:

```js
(({c}) => ({c}))(data);
```

is a short version of this one, which is better readable, in my opinion.

```js
(function(arg) {
  return { c: arg.c }
})(data);
```

So, we can convert it to arrow function to understand all the transformations, step by step.

Initially we can convert the function to use the arrow function syntax:

```js
((arg) => {
  return { c: arg: c }
})(data)
```

Then we can destructur `c` from the received argument.

```js
(({c}) => {
  return { c: c }
})(data)
```

As the created arrow function does not require a block, we can simplify it:

```js
// The parenthesis are added because the syntax () => {} is not valid.
(({c}) => ({ c: c }))(data)
```

And finally, we can use the short object syntax to make it exactly as the original one.

```js
(({c}) => ({ c }))(data)
```

So, this function generates a `{ c: <value> }` object, and therefore you can use the spread operator to merge it in the object you are building.

Comment: I know what the arrow function does, the thing I can't understand is why the first method (simple destructuring inside the object) does not work.